# File System TreeView

Tags: c#, file, treeview, path, system

Im working with file systems and I have a List<> of file objects that have the file path as a property. Basically I need to create a treeview in .NET but im struggling to think of the best way to go about doing this as I need to create a tree structure from a list like:

```
C:/WINDOWS/Temp/ErrorLog.txt
C:/Program Files/FileZilla/GPL.html
C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/ntuser.dat.LOG
```

etc....

The list is not structured at all and I cant make any changes to the current object structure.

I'm working in C#.

Many thanks for all who contribute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [populate treeview from a list of path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155977/populate-treeview-from-a-list-of-path)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you wanted to stick with the strings something like this would work...

```
TreeNode root = new TreeNode();
TreeNode node = root;
treeView1.Nodes.Add(root);

 foreach (string filePath in myList) // myList is your list of paths
 {
    node = root;
    foreach (string pathBits in filePath.Split('/'))
    {
      node = AddNode(node, pathBits);
    }
 }


private TreeNode AddNode(TreeNode node, string key)
{
    if (node.Nodes.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        return node.Nodes[key];
    }
    else
    {
        return node.Nodes.Add(key, key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome; exactly what I needed. The only change I needed to make was to change `filePath.Split('/')` to `filePath.Split('/', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` for my purposes. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I would turn the string into a FileInfo.

Once you have the [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) object, you can use the Directory property to retrieve the [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) for each path.

Once you have the DirectoryInfo for the path, it's easy to "walk up" the Parent reference in DirectoryInfo to turn each path into a list of directories + filename - ie:

```
{"C:","Windows","Temp","ErrorLog.txt"}
```

This should be fairly straightforward to insert into your treeview.  Just look for each section of the path in turn, and if it doesn't exist, add it....

Answer (score 2):

give recursion a try.

```
private void AddFiles()
{
  // Iterate your list with FileInfos here
  foreach( var fileInfo in new Collection<FileInfo>() )
  {
    GetOrCreateTreeNode( fileInfo.Directory ).Nodes.Add( new TreeNode( fileInfo.Name ) );
  }
}

private TreeNode GetOrCreateTreeNode( DirectoryInfo directory )
{
  if( directory.Parent == null )
  {
    // Access your TreeView control here:
    var rootNode = <TreeView>.Nodes[directory.Name];
    if( rootNode == null )
    {
      rootNode = new TreeNode(directory.Name);
      // Access your TreeView control here:
      <TreeView>.Nodes.Add( rootNode );
    }
    return rootNode;
  }

  var parent = GetOrCreateTreeNode( directory.Parent );
  var node = parent.Nodes[directory.Name];
  if( node == null )
  {
    node = new DirectoryNode( directory );
    parent.Nodes.Add( node );
  }
  return node;
}
```

This code should give you only an idea - I have to admit that I did not test it before posting here.

Comment: In the GetOrCreateTreeNode method, what is the Directories.Nodes[directory.Name] line meant to be? As there is no such thing as Directories.... Your help so far is very much appreciated!

Comment: Thankyou, i thought it would be that but I wanted to make sure

Answer (score 2):

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var paths = new List<string>
                        {
                            @"C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch\MUI\040C",
                            @"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727",
                            @"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MUI",
                            @"C:\WINDOWS\addins",
                            @"C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch",
                            @"C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch\MUI",
                            @"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MUI\0409"
                        };
        treeView1.PathSeparator = @"\";
        PopulateTreeView(treeView1, paths, '\\');
    }

    private static void PopulateTreeView(TreeView treeView, IEnumerable<string> paths, char pathSeparator)
    {
        TreeNode lastNode = null;
        string subPathAgg;
        foreach (string path in paths)
        {
            subPathAgg = string.Empty;
            foreach (string subPath in path.Split(pathSeparator))
            {
                subPathAgg += subPath + pathSeparator;
                TreeNode[] nodes = treeView.Nodes.Find(subPathAgg, true);
                if (nodes.Length == 0)
                    if (lastNode == null)
                        lastNode = treeView.Nodes.Add(subPathAgg, subPath);
                    else
                        lastNode = lastNode.Nodes.Add(subPathAgg, subPath);
                else
                    lastNode = nodes[0];
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: -1 Found the incorrect parent in several situations where Paul's solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

EHosca's piece worked for me perfectly, with one change - I had to set lastnode to nothing after the foreach path in paths area.

This is eHosca's code above, ported to VB.

```
Private Sub PopulateTreeView(tv As TreeView, paths As List(Of String), pathSeparator As Char)
    Dim lastnode As TreeNode = Nothing
    Dim subPathAgg As String
    For Each path In paths
        subPathAgg = String.Empty
        lastnode = Nothing
        For Each subPath In path.Split(pathSeparator)
            subPathAgg += subPath + pathSeparator
            Dim nodes() As TreeNode = tv.Nodes.Find(subPathAgg, True)
            If nodes.Length = 0 Then
                If IsNothing(lastnode) Then
                    lastnode = tv.Nodes.Add(subPathAgg, subPath)
                Else
                    lastnode = lastnode.Nodes.Add(subPathAgg, subPath)
                End If
            Else
                lastnode = nodes(0)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```