# Populate treeview from list in C#

Tags: c#, treeview, sharpsvn

I've made some researches and I found some topic close to my problem, but none of them solved it.

[populate treeview from a list of path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155977/populate-treeview-from-a-list-of-path)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/dae1c72a-dd28-4232-9aa4-5b38705c0a97

[SharpSvn: Getting repository structure and individual files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883196/sharpsvn-getting-repository-structure-and-individual-files)

I want to make a repository browser for my SVN folder so that the user can choose one folder and it will be return to a text box.

This is my actual code :

```
    private void sourceTrunkBrowseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         using (SvnClient svnClient = new SvnClient())
         {
             Collection<SvnListEventArgs> contents;
             Collection<SvnListEventArgs> contents2;
             List<TreeItem> files = new List<TreeItem>();
             if (svnClient.GetList(new Uri("https://sourcecode/svn/XXXXXX"), out contents))
             {
                 foreach (SvnListEventArgs item in contents)
                 {
                     if (item.Path != "")
                     {
                         files.Add(new TreeItem(item.Path, 0));

                         if (svnClient.GetList(new Uri("https://sourcecode/svn/XXXXX" + item.Path), out contents2) && item.Path != "")
                         {
                             foreach (SvnListEventArgs item2 in contents2)
                             {
                                 if (item2.Path != "")
                                 {
                                     files.Add(new TreeItem(item2.Path, 1));
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
             svnBrowser_.FillMyTreeView(files);
             svnBrowser_.Show();
         }
     }
```

And

```
  public void FillMyTreeView(List<AutoTrunk.TreeItem> files) 
 {

       // Suppress repainting the TreeView until all the objects have been created.
        svnTreeView.BeginUpdate();

        svnTreeView.Nodes.Clear();
        List<TreeNode> roots = new List<TreeNode>();
         roots.Add(svnTreeView.Nodes.Add("Items"));
         foreach (AutoTrunk.TreeItem item in files)
     {
         if (item.Level == roots.Count) roots.Add(roots[roots.Count - 1].LastNode);
         roots[item.Level].Nodes.Add(item.BrowsePath);
     }

        // Begin repainting the TreeView.
        svnTreeView.EndUpdate();
 }
```

But my tree look like this :

```
+---Name1
|   |
|   +------Name2
|   |
|   +------Name3
|   |
|   +------Name5
|   |
|   +------Name6
|
+---Name4
```

but Name 5 and Name 6 should be under Name 4

Sorry for the long post and thanks!

Comment: In your first `foreach (SvnListEventArgs item in contents)` loop, change the second `if` to be nested in the first `if`. You don't want the second `if` to run if the path is blank. Because then you ultimately just end up calling `GetList` for the source trunk again (IE: `"https://sourcecode/svn/XXXXXX" + path` becomes `https://sourcecode/svn/XXXXXX` if `path` is an empty string).

Comment: True, it does not solve my problem, but I'll change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if(item.Level == roots.Count)` is your problem I'm thinking... Are you sure the items have the correct level? For example, if `Name1` and `Name4` are roots, then what happens after you've encountered your second root? Does this give the intended result:

```
TreeNode root = svnTreeView.Nodes.Add("Items");
TreeNode workingNode = root;
foreach (AutoTrunk.TreeItem item in files)
{
    if (item.Level == 0) 
        workingNode = root.Nodes.Add(item.BrowsePath);
    else
        workingNode.Nodes.Add(item.BrowsePath);
}
```

Just a thought.