# How I can fill a treeView with a List<string>?

Tags: c#, string, list, collections, treeview

hi i have a question to treeview.

I have a List liste and the treeview with the name treeLic. Now I want to fill this treeview with this list. Can I do this and how?

```
XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(final_output));

           while (xr.Read())
           {
               switch (xr.Name)
               {
                   case "FEATURE":
                       if (xr.HasAttributes)
                       {
                           while (xr.MoveToNextAttribute())
                           {
                               if (xr.Name == "NAME")
                               {
                                   liste.Add(xr.Value);
                               }
                           }
                       }
                       break;

               }
           }

treeLic. ????? //fill this treeview with this list liste
```

Comment: Show your work and tell people what have you tried so far. People can't read your mind..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populate treeview from list in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724600/populate-treeview-from-list-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out.

```
XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(final_output));

       while (xr.Read())
       {
           switch (xr.Name)
           {
               case "FEATURE":
                    TreeNode root = MyTreeView.Nodes.Add("FEATURE");
                   if (xr.HasAttributes)
                   {
                       while (xr.MoveToNextAttribute())
                       {
                           if (xr.Name == "NAME")
                           {
                               TreeNode workingNode = root.Nodes.Add(xr.Value.ToString());
                               liste.Add(xr.Value);
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   break;

           }
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var nodes = XDocument.Load(fileName)
            .Descendants("FEATURE")
            .Select(f => new TreeNode((string)f.Attribute("NAME")))
            .ToArray();

treeLic.Nodes.AddRange(nodes);
```