# C# Populate treeView with files in a n-depth

Tags: c#, treeview, populate

I don't know how to show show all data in a treeview control:
here is my code:

```
 private void PopulateTree(string path, int depth, TreeNode parent)
    {
        if (depth == 0)
        {
        //This make a child
            parent.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(path);
            return;
        }
        //This makes a parent
        TreeNode first = new TreeNode(path);
        parent.Nodes.Add(first);

        foreach (var v in ListWithPaths)
        {
            PopulateTree(v, depth - 1, first);
        }
    }
```

It only seems to works when `depth=1`

```
parent
-parent
--parent
---child
---child
--parent
---child
---child
-/parent
/parent
```

This is how I see it....

Comment: It only makes one because you are continually making parent nodes and only make a child when you hit zero.  Are you using depth to indicate you want a child node?

Comment: I need something like this I updated my question

Comment: Try refactoring your code to have 2 methods one to add a parent and one to add a child.... you may need to decide ahead of time what constitutes a parent and create your collection accordingly and then just spin through the collection and populate accordingly.  Honestly there are a lot of examples if you google it...

Comment: please could you provide a link, cause I googleit but maybe I'm looking in wrong direction....

Comment: @user2508298, you have a habit of removing the body of your questions after they get answers. This is disrespectful to the users who devote time and effort to answering your questions. Please stop.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155977/populate-treeview-from-a-list-of-path) :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var paths = new List<string>
                        {
                            @"C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch\MUI\040C",
                            @"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727",
                            @"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MUI",
                            @"C:\WINDOWS\addins",
                            @"C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch",
                            @"C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch\MUI",
                            @"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MUI\0409"
                        };

        treeView1.PathSeparator = @"\";

        PopulateTreeView(treeView1, paths, '\\');
}


private static void PopulateTreeView(TreeView treeView, IEnumerable<string> paths, char pathSeparator)
    {
        TreeNode lastNode = null;
        string subPathAgg;
        foreach (string path in paths)
        {
            subPathAgg = string.Empty;
            foreach (string subPath in path.Split(pathSeparator))
            {
                subPathAgg += subPath + pathSeparator;
                TreeNode[] nodes = treeView.Nodes.Find(subPathAgg, true);
                if (nodes.Length == 0)
                    if (lastNode == null)
                        lastNode = treeView.Nodes.Add(subPathAgg, subPath);
                    else
                        lastNode = lastNode.Nodes.Add(subPathAgg, subPath);
                else
                    lastNode = nodes[0];
            }
        }
    }

        foreach (var v in ListWithPaths)
        {
            PopulateTree(v, depth - 1, first);
        }
    }
```

Based on the path, it's creating the depth.
If this is not the wished behaviour, you can change the `PopulateTreeView`-Function accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are some unclear moments in your code:

1. Do you want to explicitly restrict path depth (e.g. show paths up to 3d level only)
2. What is ListWithPaths? Can two paths have a common node?

To show a single path with restriction (depth) the code could be

```
private void PopulateTree(String path, TreeNode parent, int depth) {
  if (depth == 0) // <- Artificial criterium
    return;

  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
    return;

  int index = path.IndexOf(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

  String directoryName = (index < 0) ? path : path.Substring(0, index);
  String otherName = (index < 0) ? null : path.Substring(index + 1);

  TreeNode childNode = parent.Nodes.Add(directoryName);

  PopulateTree(otherName, childNode, depth - 1);
}
```

In order to load a collection of paths without any restriction *with possible common nodes* you can use
something like this:

```
private void PopulateTree(String path, TreeView view, TreeNode parent) {
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
    return;

  int index = path.IndexOf(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

  String directoryName = (index < 0) ? path : path.Substring(0, index);
  String otherName = (index < 0) ? null : path.Substring(index + 1);

  TreeNode childNode = null;
  TreeNodeCollection nodes = (parent == null) ? view.Nodes : parent.Nodes;

  foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
    if (String.Equals(node.Name, directoryName)) {
      childNode = node;

      break;
    }

  if (childNode == null)
    childNode = nodes.Add(directoryName);

  PopulateTree(otherName, view, childNode);
}

private void PopulateTree(IEnumerable<String> paths, TreeView view) {
  view.BeginUpdate();

  try {
    foreach (String path in paths)
      PopulateTree(path, view, null);
  }
  finally {
    view.EndUpdate();
  }
}

...

PopulateTree(ListWithPaths, MyTreeView)
```